# Intellij - gradle refresh for android project that requires a parameter

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have gradle project, the simplified android part of the build.gradle of which looks like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        def mapPlacesApiKeys = [dev_1: [api_key: 'key_1', sender_id: 'sender_id_1'], dev_9: [api_key: 'key_2', sender_id: 'sender_id_2'],prod_1: [api_key: 'key_3', sender_id: 'sender_id_3']]
        if (project.hasProperty('env')) {
            if (mapPlacesApiKeys.get(env) == null) {
                def keyset = mapPlacesApiKeys.keySet()
                throw new StopExecutionException("Value '$env' is not a valid environment value. Valid environments: $keyset. You can set an environment by passing the -Penv=<env> parameter to your gradle build.")
            }
        } 
        buildConfigField "String", "SENDER_ID", "\"${mapPlacesApiKeys.get(env).get('sender_id')}\""
        manifestPlaceholders = [maps_places_api_key: mapPlacesApiKeys.get(env).get('api_key')]
    }  
}
```

When I run this from the command line I run it with an environment parameter e.g. -Penv=dev_1. This does 2 things as you can see in the script:
a) Replaces in the androidmanifest the value "maps_places_api_key" with the actual key of the specified environment
b) Adds a String with the SENDER_ID in the BuildConfig java class.

This works fine from the command line. My problem is that in intellij (or android studio, should be the same) when I import the gradle project I get the following error:

```
-Penv is missing. You can set an environment by passing the -Penv=<env> parameter to your gradle build.
```

Which is the exception that I am declaring. So my question is how can I structure this code so that the IDE doesn't try to run it when it's loading the project.

Note that I don't want to replace the "env" parameter with any kinds of flavors or buildTypes, as there's about 15 different environments and it's gonna be a mess, but if there's another suggestion that comes in to your mind feel free to share it.

Comment: If you want the IDE doesn't try to run it when it's loading the project,When do you want IDE to run it?

Comment: Yeah, I am not quite sure on what options I got. I don't mind if it does it when it's trying to build the project (and fails) - at least I don't get spammed about gradle being out of sync all the time. Also, shouldn't there be a way to address this, pass a parameter somehow to intellij so that this project can be properly imported and built? I tried the "Script parameters" in the build configurations tab for both gradle and groovy and it didn't do anything.

Comment: I think you should add a gradle task  contains these code in build.gradle and when you want to use , run task in terminal.

Comment: That is what I thought but I am just now starting to use gradle so I'm not sure on how to do that. Is there a way to use the "manifestPlaceholders" and the "buildConfigField" from a task outside the android tag ?

Answer (score 1):

```
android{   
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.xx'
        minSdkVersion 14
    } 
    productFlavors {
        def path="./channel.txt"
        file(path).eachLine { line->
            def words = line.split(':')
            def name = words[0]
            def sender_id = words[1]
            def api_key = words[2]
            "$name" {
                buildConfigField "String", "SENDER_ID", sender_id
                manifestPlaceholders = [maps_places_api_key: api_key]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a default value for my environments as I don't want to introduce all these flavors for my different environments. Even conceptually in my mind the flavors are for different versions of the app (e.g. paid/free) not just for different environments

Comment: Update: I did end up using this in the end! Really helpful !